# How to reduce repeat log in debian 10?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, logging, rsyslog, syslog

In [similar quesiton](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/267965/system-log-full-of-session-and-slice-messages),I know `echo 'if $programname == "systemd" and ($msg contains "Starting Session" or $msg contains "Started Session" or $msg contains "Created slice" or $msg contains "Starting user-" or $msg contains "Starting User Slice of" or $msg contains "Removed session" or $msg contains "Removed slice User Slice of" or $msg contains "Stopping User Slice of") then stop' >/etc/rsyslog.d/ignore-systemd-session-slice.conf`  can be used to reduce repeat log message in `centos` system.

In debian 10, how to do it?

Comment: It didn't already work?

Comment: @MichaelHampton,there's no such a file in debian system.

Comment: It doesn't exist in CentOS either. You create it.